# azure pipeline not continuing after DockerCompose@0

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, docker-compose

I have this pipeline.yml file

```
trigger:
- master
resources:
- repo: self
variables:
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and Push image
  jobs:
   - job: Build
     displayName: Build and Push
     pool:
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

     steps:          
         
     - task: DockerCompose@0
       displayName: Build services
       inputs:
         action: Build services
         azureSubscriptionEndpoint: serviceConnection07
         dockerComposeFile: docker-compose.yml
         projectName: $(Build.Repository.Name)
         qualifyImageNames: true
         additionalImageTags: $(Build.BuildId)
               
     - task: DockerCompose@0
       displayName: Push services
       inputs:
         action: Push services
         azureSubscriptionEndpoint: serviceConnection07
         dockerComposeFile: docker-compose.yml
         projectName: $(Build.Repository.Name)
         qualifyImageNames: true
         additionalImageTags: $(Build.BuildId)

     - task: DockerCompose@0
       displayName: open browser instances
       inputs:
         containerregistrytype: 'Container Registry'
         dockerRegistryEndpoint: Dockerhub
         dockerComposeFile: '**/docker-compose.yml'
         action: 'Run a Docker Compose command'
         dockerComposeCommand: 'up'
         detached: false

     - task: Maven@3
       inputs:
         mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
         mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
         #javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
         #jdkVersionOption: '1.11'
         jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
         publishJUnitResults: true
         testResultsFiles: '**/target/cucumber.html'
         goals: 'clean verify -P acceptanceTests -e -X'
```

I see that on azure console that it opens up all firefox and chrome instances but keeps on running above `open browser instances` task and never finishes. I would like it to move to next task `Maven@3`, which is where I would like to start the tests.

I tried `detached: true` also but it gives me same result

How would I make pipeline move to `Maven@3` task ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I was missing `-d` in `dockerComposeCommand` command above. When I changed to `dockerComposeCommand: 'up -d'` , execution continued to `Maven@3` task